# Where can "is" be put in "I would like to ask you what is the difference in meaning between CAT and DOG"?

Tags: word-order

> 1 I would like to ask you what **is** the difference in meaning
> between CAT and DOG.
>
> 2 I would like to ask you what the difference in meaning between CAT
> and DOG **is**.
>
> 3 I would like to ask you what the difference in meaning **is**
> between CAT and DOG.

I think that 2 is correct, 1 is not correct but used 3 is wrong and not used.
Do you agree?

Comment: Why do you think #3 is wrong?  You can find [lots of similar examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22what+the+difference+is+between%22&biw=1752&bih=827&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AJOqlzU4nsDrXYl-734vZdjFlwo50M6ExA%3A1677002753999&ei=AQj1Y7u9PJ2y5NoPhp-s8AM&ved=0ahUKEwj7wcGLmqf9AhUdGVkFHYYPCz44ChDh1QMICA&uact=5&oq=%22what+the+difference+is+between%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAM6BQgAEKIEULsGWPkJYNMMaABwAHgAgAFDiAHYApIBATaYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) in Google Books.

Comment: Is it a solid enough argument to refer to Google Books? Do you think that all three are correct?

Comment: 1 is wrong and often people make that mistake. They put the question form in a sentence with a relative clause. What is the difference = question form.

Comment: Exactly, but isn't it that kind of mistake that even natives make?

Comment: Why make a rod for your own back with the "embedded question"? Just say *I would like to ask you the difference in meaning between CAT and DOG.* Even better, since you *are* effectively asking the question (so there's no reason to assert that you would *like* to ask it) - *What is the difference in meaning between CAT and DOG?* Even better, since it's blindingly obvious you're asking about *meaning*, *What is the difference between CAT and DOG?*

Comment: But evading a problem is not solving it in the case of the intent to understand how something works in terms of grammar. I am not asking this question because I can't recast it, I want to know the right solution to the problem as it's undoubtful that those sentences are possible.

Comment: @user1425  I don't think referring to Google Books is a complete argument, but if you find many uses of a particular sentence structure, you might re-evaluate whether it's incorrect or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What" corresponds to the complement (the difference is *something*).  In an indirect question, "what" is fronted, but the subject and verb are unchanged, producing "ask what the difference is".  So 1 is wrong.  The movable adverbial "between cat and dog" can go before or after the verb.  So both 2 and 3 are right.

Comment: I rather think that 3 is an example of [heavy-element extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition), analogous to _I want to ask who that man **was** that you spent so much time with yesterday_.